# How to extract cookie on Android in React-Native?

Tags: android, react-native, cookies

I am currently working on react-native app and I am trying to extract all cookies using react-native-cookies and this is working fine on IOS platform, but not working on Android. On Android I've tried to extract it like this:

`const cookie = await CookieManager.get(url);`

But that returns me an empty object. My question is: How to extract all the cookies on Android platform?
Thank you!

Comment: hav you properly installed and linked for android ?

Comment: I used only react-native link react-native-cookies.

Comment: what version of react native you are using? you arent using expo right?

Comment: No! I am working on extracted app. The version of react-native is 0.55

Comment: I also checked the settings.gradle file and everything is set correct